# Why enterprise wiki sub site will not have any navigation term selected for it to enable friendly urls

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, managed-navigation, enterprise-wiki, term-set

I am working on an on-premises enterprise wiki site collection 2013. now when i created a new site collection of type enterprise wiki, i have noted that inside the navigation there is already a term set named "Site Navigation" created as follow,to enable managed navigation & friendly urls:-

[image]

but when i create a new sub-site of type enterprise wiki, under the above root enterprise wiki site, i have noted that the navigation is **NOT** set to Managed Navigation,and if i manually select to have the "Current Navigation" = "Managed Navigation", then for a reason or another the above term set "Site Navigation" seems to  be hidden from the subsite:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce how i can enable friendly urls inside the sub-site? and why this is not the defualt as in the root site case?

second question. Generally speaking is there any harm if 2 enterprise wiki sites share the same term set for navigation? or each wiki site should have its own term set for managed navigation & friendly urls ?